# Can't share a link on Facebook of a file that is hosted on Resin Server

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, resin

I'm having a problem while trying to share a link to the following file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" lang="pt-br">
<head>

    <title>My Title</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="Facebook App ID here" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Site name here" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Title here" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Description here" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="Image src here" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />

    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Title here" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="Description here" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@Twitter user here" />
    <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="Image src here" />
    
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to share the link hosting the file on the Jetty web server, for example, it works normally. But, if the file is hosted on Resin Server, it seems that the file has no content when requested by Facebook bots.

The following error is returned by the Open Graph Object Debugger when I try to fetch information from this file:

> Object Missing a Required Value   Object at URL
>   'http://54.207.29.193:8090/' of type 'website' is invalid because a
>   required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

I've made tests with Resin 4.0.33 and 4.0.41, but the problem keeps happening. Furthermore, when I try to share the link on Twitter, it works normally. It's pretty weird!

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Open Graph, required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405457/facebook-open-graph-required-property-ogtitle-of-type-string-was-not-provi)